# Syntax error: Unexpected token (21:4) <Router history={props.history}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My first time to ask a question on stackoverflow. I really need some help. Let me please know you need from me. I am using React Framwork dva-js. The project runs fine at windows. Now git pull at Ubuntu, after install, got error's. First I got error below.  I found this really strange because Roadhog should include Babel.

```
     "Moule not found,cannot resolve module babel"
     "Moule not found,cannot resolve module style"
     "Moule not found,cannot resolve module css"
     "Moule not found,cannot resolve module postcss"
```

And I installed them all

```
       yarn add babel-loader style-loader css-loader postcss-loader
```

Now I got this ERROR

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (21:4)

  19 |
  20 |   return (
> 21 |     <Router
     |     ^
  22 |     history={props.history}
  23 |     // onUpdate={hashLinkScroll}
  24 |      >

   @ ./src/index.js 69:11-30
```

.webpackrc

```
{
   "extraBabelPlugins": [
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "es", "style": true }]

  ],
  "theme": {
    "@primary-color": "#1371fa"
    }
  ,
   "proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000",
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
  ,
  "env": {
    "development": {
        "extraBabelPlugins": ["dva-hmr"]
    },
    "production":{
      "publicPath":"/"
    }

  }

}
```

.babelrc

```
{ 
  "presets": ["env"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]

}
```

src/router.js

```
function RouterConfig(props) {

  return (
    <Router
    history={props.history}
    // onUpdate={hashLinkScroll}
     >
      <div>

        <Route path="/" exact  component={LayoutPage} />
        <Route path="/counter" exact component={CounterPage} />

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default RouterConfig;
```

src/index.js

```
const app = dva(
  {
    initialState: {},
    history:browserHistory,
    extraReducers: {
      form: formReducer,
    },
  }
);

// 2. Plugins
app.use(createLoading());

// 3. Model

app.model(require('./models/counter').default);


// 4. Router
app.router(require('./router').default);

// 5. Start
app.start('#root');
```

at public/index.html

```
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

What I have tried, but dosent help.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf yarn.lock
yarn install
```

Comment: You've written JSX in a JS file. Ideally it should be called `router.jsx`

Comment: Are you transiping your code using something like Babel?

Comment: anywhere you use jsx, you need to import react in that file, also you need  "@babel/preset-react" to transpile your code

Comment: Sryy, I have provided more informatie of my .webpackrc and .babelrc 
I use React framwork dva-js and roadhog  which includes Babel.